# Github hook bash script not pulling

Tags: php, git, bash, shell, sh

I have a github account set up to my EC2 server with no issues. When i try to run a bash script to 'git pull' it wont do it. I will do a 'git status' and many other commands. Here is my sh file

```
cd /var/www/html/TDS/;
ls -la;
type git;

git status;
git remote -v;

git pull origin master;

echo "hello world";
```

All lines work except the git pull. I have tried git pull, git pull origin master, git fetch, git fetch origin master. I have ruled out all possibilities like permission issues and privileges.

This sh file is executed by hitting a PHP page, the PHP page looks like this

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/bin/sh /var/www/html/TDS/git.sh');
print_r("<pre>$output</pre>"); 
?>
```

Very simple and it works minus the Pull request. Any help would be amazing, I'm so close to getting this to work.

Comment: Any error output from the `git pull` failure?

Comment: I agree with @Oliver. Maybe something is going to standard err that you're not catching.

Comment: Nothing comes back, no error.

Answer (score 2):

For a `git pull` to work, the user running it must have write permissions to the git repo's index (under `.git/`).  Make sure the user under which the script is run (Apache?) has those rights.

Comment: so i need to 
    chown apache.apache ./git?

Comment: i have made that file user apache and group apache, still didnt work, i also tried 777 and that didnt work either

Comment: The Apache user needs SSH access to the remote repo, and I don't know of any clean and secure way of doing this.  I've had this problem before with a Rails app running under Phusion Passenger, and all we had to do is set it up so Passenger runs the app under an actual user with a home directory into which the SSH key was configured.  This is as secure as you want it to be, by giving that user only the necessary permissions.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

...does PHP (www-data) have permissions? Is it the owner of the file?

Comment: apache.apache has the prrmissions

Comment: user is Apache and group is Apache

Comment: The file works without issues manually. Using su apache in the sh file before running the git pull it does nothing.

Comment: I meant typing su apache in the console (which logs you in as apache) and THEN running the file :)

Comment: su apache returns this This account is currently not available.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an ssh URL to the origin repository?  Do you have ssh-agent running when you do it manually?  Have you provided ssh agent access to the shell script (hint, the answers are Yes, Yes, No.  Probably.)

So we have determined it is ssh access that is the problem.  You then have two choices:  getting ssh-agent credentials into the php process and allowing the php script access to ssh credentials without requiring a password.  Both are problematic one way or another.

To get assh-agent credentials into the php process, copy the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK environmental variable from a shell into your php/shell script `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-wScioBA10361/agent.10361 git pull`.  Then assuming the php script has sufficient privs to access that file, git pull will work.  This is problematic because you need to ssh into the system to get the auth sock, change the program to use the new socket (or write a program to find the current socket), and leave everything running.  Log out, reboot, etc and you will lose git pull functionality.

The other option is to create ssh credentials for the php/shell user who is running `git pull`.  Find the home directory, create .ssh, and ssh-keygen new keys for that user.  You can set up the private key to not have a password so that anyone who can access this file (security risk!!) can ssh using those credentials.  Add the public key to the authorized keys of the account who has access to the git repo (gitolite would allow you to restrict what privileges that account might have).

Comment: The cloned url was a ssh url. Yes ssh-agent is running, dopnt know on  the last one how would i check that?

Comment: @Casey Becking: Added information on two ways you can provide the ssh command git-pull uses the credentials to access the remote repository.